# Read matrices as cell array from long longitudinal matlab data

Tags: matlab, cell-array, matrix-indexing

Assume the following hypothetical Matlab data (as column vectors): for 3 subjects (i=1 to 3) each provides three measurements y1, y2 , y3, over 5 time points (j=1 to 5) or less (unbalanced). The original data set is bigger. so I need to use cell array. I need at the end have Y=cell(3,1), such that, for a subject i, Y{i} is a matrix represents the repeated measures for subject i.

```
i   j   y1  y2  y3

1   1   1.0 0.6 0.8
1   2   0.8 0.7 0.2
1   3   1.0 0.7 0.9
1   4   1.0 0.8 0.7
1   5   0.7 0.8 0.9

2   1   0.5 0.7 0.8
2   2   0.4 0.7 0.6
2   3   0.4 0.5 0.8

3   1   0.4 0.5 0.7
3   2   0.5 0.6 0.8
3   3   0.5 0.6 0.8
3   4   0.6 0.6 0.8
```

So I need them look like

```
Y{1}=       
1.0 0.6 0.8
0.8 0.7 0.2
1.0 0.7 0.9
1.0 0.8 0.7
0.7 0.8 0.9

Y{2}=       
0.5 0.7 0.8
0.4 0.7 0.6
0.4 0.5 0.8

Y{3}=       
0.4 0.5 0.7
0.5 0.6 0.8
0.5 0.6 0.8
0.6 0.6 0.8
```

I need also to use i and j to help in indexing

Comment: The question is not clear. What does the original look like (i.e. what does *unbalanced* mean)? In what format is it (e.g. text file, Matlab array)? What do you expect as an output? A small example with a few lines of *unbalanced* input and the expected output will help to understand what you exactly want -- and get a useful answer.

Comment: Please edit the question, this is not readable in a comment

Comment: @Brice, I felt it was not readable so I edit the question and tried to clarify. Wish it is clear now. Unbalanced means the matrix of each cell in Y is not of the same size. the first is 5X3, second 3X3 , last is 4X3.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that the input data is contained in 5 vectors called `i`, `j`, `y1`, `y2` and `y3`. You may use the following code:

```
% Initialize Y
Y = cell(max(i),1);

% Loop to read
for kk=1:max(i)
    sel = (i==kk); % Logical array use to select lines according to i
    ind = j(sel);  % This is in case the input data is not sorted, we'll know where the data has to go in Y{...}
    % Start with last column so that Y{ii} is initialized with the good size
    Y{kk}(ind,3) = y3(sel);
    Y{kk}(ind,2) = y2(sel);
    Y{kk}(ind,1) = y1(sel);
end
```

If all the data is already sorted by `i` & `j`, you could use `mat2cell`. A loop would still be needed to know the number of lines for each value of `i`:

```
% Initialize Y
count = zeros(max(i),1);

% Loop to count
for kk=1:max(i)
    count(kk)=(i==kk);
end
Y = mat2cell([y1,y2,y3] , count);
```

(As a side note, the use of `i` and `j` as variable names is not recommended as it may lead to a confusion with the imaginary unit `i` and may affect performance. Mathworks recommends to use other variable names, and use `1i` or `1j` when referring to the imaginary unit.)

Comment: your first code results in an error, I modified two lines then it work but I cant post the code in a neat way in the comment as ctrl+k does not define the selected line as code here

Comment: You may use backquotes ` around code snippets in comments. This is also how you put code inline in questions & answers.

Comment: The modified code is // `N=max(i1);
Y = cell(1,N);
for kk=1:N
    sel = (i1==kk); 
    Y{kk} = [y1(sel),y2(sel),y3(sel)];
end`// I can not find how to enter new line in the comment??

Comment: I got it. As regards running the code in my last comment on the full data set I need to add another command line in the loop to get rid of NAN vectors for unbalanced subjects, the final code that works fine with my full data is `N=max(i1);
Y = cell(1,N);

for kk=1:N
    sel = (i1==kk); 
 

   yy = [y1(sel),y2(sel),y3(sel)];
   yy(any(isnan(yy), 2), :) = [];
   Y{kk} = yy;
end`